# integrate google search in website

Tags: html, css, search, web, google-search

I have a domain and want to integrate a startsite for my chrome without anyone else knowing it, but that is not my problem, I want to integrate a google search engine so that you can search and forwards to results on google.

```
<style type="text/css">
button{
width:128px;
height: 128px;
left: 40%;
position: relative;
}

button img{
width: 128px;
height: 128px;
margin-left: -8px;
margin-top: -4px;
}

input{
height: 45px;
width: 300px;
font-size: 18px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #fff;
padding-left: 20px;
text-align: center;
left: 32%;
position: relative;
}
</style>

<button><img src="youtube.jpg"></button>

<br>

<input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search on google here">
```

Comment: So what's your question? And before you say, "how do I do it?", remember that questions like that are too broad and will be closed as such. So if you've written any code thus far I highly recommend adding it to your question. You should read "[how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: i edited the post and i mean that if you type in "cute cats" in the search box you would get forwarded to "https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=cute+cats&*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of free alternatives to do that for you.

Try Google Custom Search if you want something more specific:

https://cse.google.com/cse/

Comment: I was thinking of a open search-bar that searches the whole web(not deep web :D) instead of specific websites, but this would be perfect otherwise